# Angularjs ng-repeat values printing issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scope variable call items in the angular controller with an object array.It is in the following format and this is the way it's showing in chrome console,

```
data
Array[4]
0
:
Object
created_at
:
"2016-12-29 08:20:21"
id
:
1
name
:
"Developer questions"
question_classification_type_id
:
1
status
:
1
updated_at
:
"2016-12-29 08:20:21"
```

So this is my ng-repeat directive in html.

```
<span ng-repeat="result in items track by $index">
<p>{{result.name}}</p>
<p>{{result.description}}</p>
</span>
```

But it's not showing anything in the view.I can't figure it out the reason for this since I have done similar stuff before without any issues.So please help someone to solve this.

Comment: what's error you got?

Comment: I don't get any errors in my console relating to this.

Comment: I tried with that.But still it's not showing.

Comment: update your exact object here

Comment: Can you print out the array in the view without ng-repeat ? The first thing I will do is to check whether the view is within the correct scope and it can access the variable.

Comment: Post your object here.

Comment: A good way to check.Thanks, I'll first check in that way.

Comment: I followed that way. But even in that way, i can't see anything.

Comment: @CodeCanyon Better you post your object (items Array)

Comment: @NagaveerGowda - I think i have already posted it here.

Comment: post your controller plz

Comment: This is one of my office projects.Therefore i can't post my controller code here.But i'm assigning it to $scope.items variable.And data is retrieving through an angular service.And it's accessing a php rest service to fetch data.I'm 100% sure data is retrieving form the other end.

Comment: @CodeCanyon I don't see any problem with ng-repeat. Could be problem in controller only

Comment: @NagaveerGowda - OK, i will thoroughly check it again then.

Comment: try to print the array like `{{items}}` , and see if there is data coming properly or not ?

Comment: Yes, i tried that way.But i can't see nothing. But in the same controller i'm accessing a function for the same view. But it's working.

Comment: so there is some problem in the items array , in controller how the `items` array is defined. Is it like `$scope.items=...` or not?

Comment: are you trying to show this array in different views?

Comment: No not in different views.Only in one view.

Comment: Thanks all i could able to solve this :) Issue was it used pagination to show the values.So first i needed to access the paginate object first.

Answer (score 0):

`result.description` there is no description in the items array you provided and if you won't post some controller code we give examples like below it self and compare with this and try to identify what your missing.My advice is to console that $scope.items after assigning data from service or api and check with the format i provided....some times its may looks like res.data or data.data.....

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {
      "created_at":"2016-12-29 08:20:21",
      "id":1,
      "name":"Developer questions",
      "question_classification_type_id":1,
      "status":1,
      "updated_at":"2016-12-29 08:20:21"
      
    },
 {
      "created_at":"2016-12-30 08:20:21",
      "id":2,
      "name":"Developer answers",
      "question_classification_type_id":1,
      "status":1,
      "updated_at":"2016-12-30 08:20:21"
      
    },
]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <pre>{{items}}</pre>
<span ng-repeat="result in items track by $index">
<p>{{result.name}}</p>
<p>{{result.description}}</p>
</span>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But my array is bit different i think. It has an array index number as well before the object such as 0,1,2,...